# obcd_prepare using ? and a string

Tags: sql, odbc

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.
According to the official documentation, "If you wish to store a string which actually begins and ends with single quotes, you must add a space or other non-single-quote character to the beginning or end of the parameter, which will prevent the parameter from being taken as a file name." (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php)

But I am definitively not able to make it work. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT into MYTABLE values (?, 0, getdate())";
$prepare = odbc_prepare($connection, $sql);
$aaa = "aaa";
$a = odbc_execute($prepare, array($aaa)); /* here is the issue */
```

How could I fix it? Thank you

Comment: What issue? Where's the single quote?

Comment: There's no single quote but the query doen't want to insert the $aaa string into the DB, because of this.

Comment: Because of what? The document you quoted only affects string value that starts and ends with a single quote. If your string does not both start and end with a single quote, it doesn't have anything to do with that. Is your `$a` FALSE? What's the value of `odbc_errormsg()`?

Comment: For example
$sql  = "SELECT count(*) as NB from USERS_ACTIVITIES where USA_ACTIVITY_ID='$i' and (USA_USER_ID in
    (SELECT REL_USER_ID FROM RELATIONSHIPS WHERE REL_FRIEND_ID =? AND REL_STATUS = 1)
    OR USA_USER_ID IN
    (SELECT REL_FRIEND_ID FROM RELATIONSHIPS WHERE REL_USER_ID =? AND REL_STATUS = 1))";
    $res = odbc_prepare($connection, $sql);
    odbc_execute($res, array($wwid,$wwid));

doesn't work.

odbc_errormsg($connection) = (in french) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Erreur de syntaxe ou violation d'accès

Comment: Google Translate tell me that only means "Syntax error or access violation".If your `$wwid` does not start and end with a single quote, I highly doubt this error has anything to do with the single-quote problem. Have you tried to run the same query on some DB client?

Comment: In the query, if I replace the '?' with '$wwid' everything works :/

Comment: What's the full content of `$wwid`?

Comment: Something like 'eyijg255EJjI699Ti'

Comment: If your string actually contains a single quote, your "flatten" query (use actual value instead of `?`) should be `REL_FRIEND_ID='''eyijg255EJjI699Ti'''`, not `REL_FRIEND_ID='eyijg255EJjI699Ti'`. Is your IDs actually starts and ends with a single quote?

Comment: No, alphanumerics only :/

Comment: Then you **DON'T** have to quote them when doing data-binding. This is a fundamental understanding of data binding: anything that corresponds to `?` placeholder has already been treated as _data_, not _part of the SQL query_, so you don't have to quote/escape them, just leave them as-is.

Comment: For example, if normally you do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='abc'`, in data-binding style you do: `prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?")` -> `execute($res,array("abc"))`, **NOT** `execute($res,array("'abc'"))`.

Comment: In my case I'm doing odbc_execute($prepare, array($aaa)); were $aaa = "aaa". Is this the right way to do?

Comment: If your query is `INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES ('aaa')`, in binding style you do `prepare("INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (?)")` (no single quote) -> `execute($res,array("aaa"))` (again, no single quote).